# Are there any trials of old MS Outlook versions?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2003

I have to test a new email newsletter-campaign for a client. Since the results on [emailonacid.com](http://www.emailonacid.com/) for MS Outlook were kind of inconclusive I have to test it locally on my dev-machine.

So how on earth can I get some trial versions of any old Outlook? All the sites and links I found redirect to Office 2010. In particular I'd need Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2007.

I am thankful for hints of any kind..

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing software for MS-Office 2003 then you really should own a license for it because, technically, you are using it.

Although Microsoft has retired pages on their web site for obtaining MS-Office 2003 trial versions, there are many resellers/vendors who have installation CDs for MS-Office 2003, and some may still have licenses in stock that you can purchase.  If all you need is OutLook, then the "Basic Edition" of MS-Office 2003 should suffice (it includes MS-OutLook, MS-Excel, and MS-Word).

Comment: @Randolf - Just a reminder you're still an unregistered user and your rep is tracked on the basis of your cookie. Try to not wipe out the cookie ;) else do register. Cheers

Comment: @Sathya I just ate his cookie... I'm sorry =(

Comment: @BloodPhilia LOL :))

Comment: @Randolf: I just need one day with every Outlook version - The idea to get Office 2003 and 2007 for a single debugging-session and throw it away afterwards is not very appealing to me :)
Since I am a programmer I understand your argument, but in this very specific case the licences have no intrinsic value for me..